# Is there an option to search for all queues in an exchange that are bound to key X

Tags: binding, routes, rabbitmq, messaging

I have man queues in production.
I suspect one of them is bounded to routing key X by mistake.
Can I search for all queues in an exchange that are bound to a specific key by its name ?

Comment: You can get all the bindings in which a given exchange is the source or destination via the management HTTP api: /api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source or /api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/destination. details: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html

Comment: post that as an answer, not a comment, Teddy

Comment: Thanks for reminding, Derick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this out in the web UI (by default http://localhost:15672 an you should have management plugin enabled btw), just go to exchanges, click on the exchange you want and then click on bindings.

Answer (score 0):

*Moved to an asnwer from the comment.* You can get all the bindings in which a given exchange is the source or destination via the management HTTP api: /api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source or /api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/destination. details: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html